# Why is ASP.NET core 3.1 [Remote] validation not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, remote-validation

I'm coding in ASP.NET core 3.1 and I want to add the [Remote] attribute on my model. I looked at the [official documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#remote-attribute) and coded something like that:

**Code at my controller "ClientController":**

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
public IActionResult IsNameAvailable(string name) {
    return Json(false);
}
```

**Code at my model:**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
[StringLength(80, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Name length must be between 3 to 80 characters.")]
[Remote(action: "IsNameAvailable", controller: "Client", ErrorMessage = "It's working.")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

But it's not working. To be exact, it seems that the action doesn't get triggered at all. I tried adding some breakpoints or throw errors inside the `IsNameAvailable` and nothing.

I searched a bit about remote validation and I really got confused, because everyone is doing something different and nothing works for me:

1. I tried added jQuery scripts on my view / Layout page, nothing happens. Also, is that necessary?
2. I installed the jQuery.Validation NuGet package.
3. Right before the `IsNameAvailable` action I changed the `[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]` to `[HttpPost]`. I also added `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` and some other things, but no luck.
4. I changed the action from `IActionResult IsNameAvailable` to `async Task<IActionResult>` or `JsonResult`. (No idea what all of that means.)
5. I was so desperate I even tried the `controller: "ClientController"` instead of `controller: "Client"` but of course that wasn't the case.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where are you trying to call this? Can you show your javascript code as well?

Comment: @pquest I haven't made changes in the js code for that. Do I have to? I didn't find anything for it, can you explain me what I have to do?

Comment: I have never used this, but reading the docs you linked, this remote feature seems to tie in to the Jquery remote validation feature. https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Answer (score 0):

Does your controller have `[ApiController]` attribute? This attribute enables the validation by default.

Otherwise you may check your `ModelState` directly.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

If this doesn't help, you'll need to you show us the contoller's code, so we have more context to work off of.

Source:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#automatic-http-400-responses
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#apicontroller-attribute

Comment: No, it doesn't have the [ApiController] attribute, in the tutorials / posts I searched no one mentioned it for remote validation. I added it, but now I'm getting errors, currently working on them.